# Why my flutter app stop working suddenly?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

last night the flutter app was running on the simulator properly.
but today when i typed flutter run it give me this error:

```
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...          11.7s
E/AndroidRuntime(12440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12440): Process: com.example.alselre, PID: 12440
E/AndroidRuntime(12440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alselre/com.example.alselre.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.alselre.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3551)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)       
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.alselre.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity 
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1339)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3538)
E/AndroidRuntime(12440):        ... 12 more
```

I haven't changed anything...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know the reason and solution.